# How can I cast from one class to another class in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Suppose there are three classes:

One is:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Table(name = "tbl_a")
public class A {
    @Id
    @DocumentId
    @GeneratedValue(generator="rwSpecSeq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="rwSpecSeq", sequenceName="RW_SPEC_SEQ")
    private int id;
    private String sampleAttribute;

    //Getters and Setters
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("b")
public class B extends A {
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("c")
public class C extends A {
}
```

If one object is saved as B's object then if again I want to cast or change the object to C then it is giving class cast exception. Please tell me how to cast class in hibernate when merging.

My approach was something like this:

```
//Assuming that the object is C class' object.
A a = adminService.getA(request.getParameter("id"));
//before merging I did this
B b = (B)a;
adminService.save(b);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just can't. Hibernate keeps the objects type when they are persisted to the database. And Java prevents casting objects from one type to another when they are incompatible.

In your case, you can't cast an instance of `C` in `B`. It would be like casting a `String` into an `Integer`.

Your best shot is to write a method that takes an instance of `C` and copies all the attributes of `C` into a new object of type `B`.

Comment: Yup. This isn't a hibernate problem per se; it is a Java problem.

Comment: It is not even a Java problem, it is an implementation/design problem

Answer (score 0):

What does the `adminService.getA(request.getParameter("id"));` actually do? If it does something like:

hibernateSession.get(A.class,id);

then Hibernate will fetch the corresponing values from the row with that id, and create an instance of the class A you passed as argument (that's why you pass it there, from the javadocs: "Return the persistent **instance of the given entity class** with the given identifier"). This means that even if you've declared your Hibernate inheritance such that Entity C extends Entity B extends Entity A, and the corresponing classes extend eachothers in the same way, Hibernate will actually create an instance of A (not an instance of B or C which you adress as A), so that instance of A cannot be cast to B.

If however the id there corresponds to a row which is of type B (let's say), then if you do

```
A a = hibernateSession.get(B.class,id);
```

then you can do

```
B b = (B)a;
```

because your "a" objet is infact of type B (even though you initially treat it as A). However in this situation it would be simpler to just do:

```
   B b = hibernateSession.get(B.class,id);
```

Again, the above will work if you actually saved an entity of type B (or C) in the row with that id (i.e. your discriminator colum contains the value for type B or C)